# Populate dictionary with access table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm building a windows form app inside of visual studio. I have an access database table with an `OperatorID` and `OperatorName` column. I'm trying to to connect to the database, and pull this information into a dictionary on Initializing the form.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nickcoa\Desktop\forming mach report1.accdb";
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT OperatorName from OperatorsTbl", conn);
}
```

I believe I have made a connection to the database, I just can't wrap my head around the dictionary side.

My end result is to populate the dictionary with the operator name and ID number.

Comment: `SELECT OperatorID, OperatorName FROM ...`

Comment: one way to work with [OleDbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

Comment: Lots of tutorials, explanations, and code out there. Search for ado.net and DataReader.

Answer (score 0):

My "preferred" method for getting key, value pairs from a table into a dictionary is outlined as follows:

1. Create a model class object "anOperator" which models the key-value pair
   (OperatorName, OperatorID) for example.
2. Create a Data Access "DA" class to connect to the database. Include a constructor on that class which accepts a connection string and a function to get All Operators into a list of the anOperator objects.
3. Create a Business Logic "BL" class which acts between the Form and the Data Access. Include a constructor which accepts an instance of the DA class. This BL will actually generate the dictionary object for the form.

I know it seems like a lot of files and "using" statements, but the functions inside each of these classes will be very simple at first and can grow as your needs do.

- the Form will set a variable to a new instance of the "DA" object
  passing into it the connection string. {this is string injection}
- the Form will next set a variable to a new instance of the "BL"
  object passing into it the "DA" object previously created. {this is dependency injection}
- finally the Form will set a new dictionary variable to the return from execution of a "BL" function with a return type of dictionary:

> ```
> Dictionary(<int>,<string>) myDictionary = myBL.getOperatorsAsDictionary();
> ```

I'll show you below what that BL function could look like:

> ```
> public Dictionary(<int>,<string>) getOperatorsAsDictionary ()
> {
>     return theDA.getAllOperators().ToDictionary(x=>x.OperatorID, x=>x.OperatorName);
> }
> ```

Sorry that I didn't give you every single line you need in all three objects,  but I hope the 3 main concepts are present so you will be in good shape for improvements in the future.

Comment: PS -- I tried to strike a balance here between rigor and convenience without overwhelming the OP!